# How do you get a button in DIV not call the <div> click event

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, events

I have a  which has it own onClick() event.
I want the user to be able to click anywhere in the div to perform an action (flipping the card over).
However, there is also a button in that DIV as well.  For the button, I do not want it to call the div's onClick() (so don't flip card over).

```
<div onClick={this.handleClick}>
    <button onClick={this.buttonClickEvent}>menu</button>
</div>
```

Any idea on how to perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using stopPropagation() with IDs

```js
const div = document.querySelector('#div');
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');

div.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // do something here
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('div');
});

btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // do something here
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log('button');
});
```

```css
#div {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  div
  <button id="btn">menu</button> div
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stopPropagation()` method. It  prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases. So, your `buttonClickEvent` will look like this:

```
  buttonClickEvent = (e) => {
    // do smth here
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
```